# How to select a directory instead of a file in a Save As dialog in VSTO?

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, add-in

I am creating an Excel Add-In with VSTO and C#, and I would like to set the directory where the Add-In resulting files are saved (their filenames are programmatically generated).

I tried using `SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();` in my C# file but the Save File As Dialog didn't enable me to select a directory…

Could you help me with the properties of `saveDlg` that I must set?

Thank you?

Comment: You can use the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options for you:

```
string fileName;
string folderName;

//Option 1
// FolderBrowserDialog - returns only path to the folder
FolderBrowserDialog fileFolderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
fileFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
folderName = fileFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
fileName = string.Concat(fileSaveAsDialog.FileName, "\\", "your generated file name.xlsx");

//Option 2
//FileDialog - returns full path to the file
//TODO: Set up this dialog with proper file extensions
FileDialog fileSaveAsDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
fileSaveAsDialog.AddExtension = true;
fileSaveAsDialog.Filter = "Excel Workbooks (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx|Excel Macro-Enabled Workbooks | *.xlsm |All files *.*| *.*";
fileSaveAsDialog.ShowDialog();
fileName = fileSaveAsDialog.FileName;

//Option 3
// Excel SaveAs method
// if file full name is generated programatically - 
// you may save it without prompting user
Excel.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Excel.Workbook xlWB = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook; //or new Excel.Workbook(); or .Workbooks["Workbook name"]
fileName = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\my Excel wb.xlsx";
xlWB.SaveAs(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used FolderBrowserDialog instead, as in the following code:

```
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string directory = folderDlg.SelectedPath;

                string fileName = directory + "\\" + MyGeneratedFileName();

                … saves the file …     
            }
```